# How do I fix dictionary changed size during iteration: pygame radar

Tags: python, pygame

I've been trying to get this python script to use an ultrasonic sensor as a radar simulation. Every time I run the code it works for 3 seconds then exits and returns error: dictionary changed size during iteration.

I am very stuck and don't know where to start. I've looked through the entire code and cant find the problem let alone: dictionary. Maybe its just that I'm inexperience but help would be appreciable. Full original source code can be found here: https://github.com/AmrMohamed-95/radar-simulation

```
pi@Pi01:~/radar-simulation/src $ python3 radar.py
pygame 1.9.4.post1
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
dictionary changed size during iteration
Radar Exit
pi@Pi01:~/radar-simulation/src $
```

It should display a radar that continuously refreshes but it quits after two revolutions.

Comment: Could you please post the code you are running here, and the full traceback? Thanks!

Comment: Ok. If you want the full source code from the original developer visit: https://github.com/AmrMohamed-95/radar-simulation

Comment: Did you make any changes to the code or are you just trying to run it as-is? If the latter, you should probably just raise an issue with the developer.

Comment: I did edit the code to adapt it to python 3 a bit as there were some errors in the print function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is Python 2 code, so run it with Python 2 (and not Python 3, as you have been doing), e.g.

```
pi@Pi01:~/radar-simulation/src $ python radar.py
```

---

## EDIT

As for the error you are observing, it happens when you issue a `del` of a `dict` element while iterating through it, e.g.:

```
d = {x, str(x): for x in range(10)}

for k, v in d.items():
    if k == 7:
        del d[k]  # <--- error here!
```

This may cause inconsistent behaviors and it is considered bad practice even if the error was not showing up.

To fix it, you should rewrite your code to avoid `del ...`

In that codebase, that seems to happen in [`display.py` line 106](https://github.com/AmrMohamed-95/radar-simulation/blob/0bf791ab37edf9f184aff97fe9af26fd92a92a7f/src/display.py#L106).

Comment: Ok I will try that. I also had trouble installing cv2 b on python2 but it worked on python3

Comment: Python 2 is being abandoned by the end of the year. New code should not have been using it since some ~5 years, to the least and many major codebases have pledged to unplug Python by then https://python3statement.org/

Comment: Thank you for your help. It worked, and now does not return any error. I ran it as python2.7 and removed  import cv2 from radar.py and now it works with no problems except that the servo doesn't work but I should be able to figure that one out myself. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: @TimLi cool! If this answer solved your issue, please consider to upvote / accept it ;-)

Comment: @norok2 You could also talk about the trick of wrapping the `d.items()` into a `list` call to avoid this error.

Comment: @MegaIng that is anyway risky business because the `list` and the `dict` could still share references to the same objects. A cleaner approach is to collect stuff "to remove" and create a new `dict` with only the surviving stuff.